# Unable to free memory for a given Maya type

Tags: c++, memory, maya

In C++, I can reserve some memory and then delete this memory, like:

```
float *myFloat;
myFloat = new float[10];
delete myFloat;  --> Works fine
```

However if the type is not a `float *` but a `MTransformationMatrix *` (Maya type), then I am unable to delete:

```
MTransformationMatrix *myTransformationMatrixes;
myTransformationMatrixes = new MTransformationMatrix[10];
delete myTransformationMatrixes;   --> Crash
```

Is there anything I need to do for special types in order to free memory ?

Comment: `delete` what you `new`, and `delete[]` what you `new[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these allocated objects are arrays, you should use the `delete[]` syntax to delete them:

```
float *myFloat = new float[10];
delete[] myFloat;

MTransformationMatrix *myTransformationMatrixes;
myTransformationMatrixes = new MTransformationMatrix[10];
delete[] myTransformationMatrixes;
```

Both of your examples invoke undefined behavior, you are just lucky the first one did not cause visible harm.

Comment: I would consider the first one *un*luckier than the second.

Comment: @user2079303: that's debatable: if you were a passenger of a passer by and the self driving car does not crash when its almighty on board controller executes the first, you might think differently.

Comment: Sure, but we don't deploy untested code in production, now do we? Much less the people who design self driving cars. I'd take a bug that crashes on first test over a bug that doesn't - but is not guaranteed not to crash - any day. A bug that crashes the self driving car consistently is much more likely to be fixed by the time it's released, than a bug that didn't happen to crash when it was tested.

Comment: @user2079303: I wouldn't be so optimistic about their methodology until I've seen it, and still then I would be wondering what I missed.

Comment: delete myFloat would not crash but leaves memory allocated for 9 of them, because the c++ specification says it deletes only the first one. delete myTransformationMatrixes will always crash because it call the internal Maya memory manager and the destructor for each item you deallocate, and there is a mismatch in the numbers.

Comment: @cyrille: only the first gets deleted, that is only the first has its destructor invoked.  But the de-allocation is done incorrectly and invokes undefined behavior, which may or may not have a visible effect.

Answer (score 1):

You should delete arrays with `delete[]` operator.
Use `delete` when only a single object is allocated, not an array.

When You use the wrong one, it will cause undefined behaviour.